# Is this a valid way to add two strings together in c?

Tags: c, string

I have a function taking two strings `string_one` and `string_two` both a pointer to a character.

I thought of a way to add them together:

```
while (*string_one){
    string_one++;
    }
    *string_one = *string_two;
```

but I can't see the second string in the output!

How do I add two strings toghether? did I go any close?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write

```
*string_one = *string_two;
```

you are just copying one character since you are de-referencing a char pointer

to add two strings to one another you need to overwrite the \0 on the first string and then append the characters from the second string (provided you have space enough to do so).

so this

```
while (*string_one) {
  string_one++;
}
*string_one = *string_two;
```

will only overwrite the \0 with the first character from string_two which will result in the first string will not be null terminated any longer.

instead you should so do something similar again like

```
while (*string_one) {
  string_one++;
}
while (*string_two) {
  *string_one++ = *string_two++;
}
*string_one = '\0';
```

again with the premise that string_one originally pointed to a character string large enough to hold both strings.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try your code at all?

First, you need to make sure that there is enough space for both strings. Concatenating strings and not checking that there is enough space for both is probably the cause of 50% of all hacked computers in the world.

Second, a C string is an array of char with a zero byte as the last char. Your code overwrites the zero byte at the end of string_one with the first char of string_two.

Third, there is a function named strcat in the standard C library doing exactly what you want to do. It doesn't check whether there is enough space, you have to do that before the call.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, your code is not valid.

```
 *string_one = *string_two;
```

will copy the first element of `string_two` to `string_one`. This never *adds* anything. Moreover, you need to *append* the complete *string*, not only one element.

What you need is `strcat()`. You can find more on that [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat).

The general description :

> The `strcat()` function appends the `src` string to the `dest` string, overwriting the terminating null byte (`\0`) at the end of `dest`, and then adds a terminating null byte. The strings may not overlap, and the `dest` string must have enough space for the result. If `dest` is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable.